# How to disable Boost Concept Check

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, cpp-netlib

For compiling the C++ Net Lib project under Windows with Visual Studio 2008, I need to disable the Concept Check (see this thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cpp-netlib/G-hM25EnCWA/gdsHBaVfmggJ)

The compilation works in Release but not in Debug (failure at .cpp compilation)

I managed the get the compilation of the header succeed by defining NDEBUG before including the client header. How ever, this fails later, when the linker wants to link against the Release version of Boost.system library: while I'm using a Debug. I get this error :

6>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_50.lib'

I wanted to prevent this with BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB but it still wants to links against the release version (my projet links against 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_50.lib' (the debug library))

Is there a simple macro to define before including the header and which will disable the Boost.ConceptCheck stuff, like it is done in Release build? I've not found any information in the Boost documentation, neither in the header files themselves.

Many thanks

Gaetan

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do:

```
#include <boost/concept/assert.hpp>
// redefine concept assert, suppress the warning etc.
#undef BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT
#define BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT(Model)
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>

struct not_an_iterator
{};


int main()
{
  BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((InputIterator<not_an_iterator>));
  return 0;
}
```

This will make concept_assert do nothing, but I fear it is not going
to prevent your linker errors, which seem obscure.

Comment: I'd `#undef BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT` before redefining it

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, made the change.